# What is the exact difference of lightning component framework and Aura Framework?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

if Lightning component Framework is a subset of Aura framework then
What are the features that are common for both aura and Lightning Component Framework and what are the features that Aura framework has exclusively?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/what-is-the-difference-between-aura-and-lightning-frameworks-in-salesforce/

Comment: By the way, if you want to develop modern components outside of Salesforce, don't consider Aura but instead go directly to use of [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). If you are looking to develop on the Salesforce platform then use [LWCs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc) instead of Aura if at all possible since these are based on web components and the modern component architecture available within browsers.

Comment: Oh, this is a big question. Aura framework is a thing for making Lightning components. LWC is also a framework for making Lightning components. They both can live in the Lightning component environment, but only LWC can live actually outside.